# Plant identification: San Francisco, USA

Tags: botany, species-identification, homework, book-recommendation

[image]

I am taking a biology lab class and I need to identify all these plants which are from the San Francisco area.

My question is how can I find the right keyword to find their names on internet? Or can you recommend any book that I can find in library?

Comment: some pictures with more details would be great. the plants are all quit jung - which make it difficult. also some additional inforamtion about the context: it look a little bit like a peatland?  is it a kind of garden? or what is the type of landuse in your side?

Comment: Those are grow under the shade of the pine cone tree which is near by my college. I have no idea how to use the word to find them on google. Yes I can post clearly picture if you would like to help me pick some word to find them. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to refrain from giving you the answers because the point of the assignment is to  learn how to do it yourself.

You should likely start  by using a dichotomous key (likely provided by  your instructor).

You could also try  searching the [Jepson California eflora](http://ucjeps.berkeley.edu/eflora/) or [CNPS Identifying Native Plants](http://www.cnps.org/cnps/grownative/identification.php) for online keys.

Check out  the [California Native Plant Exchange website](http://www.cnplx.info/) if you don't know the name of the plant but know the general area where you saw it.

If you don't know what general type of plant  you have,   you should try keying  the plants to family  first  to get better search terms.  Try [here](http://ucjeps.berkeley.edu/IJM_fam_key.html).

If you don't know plant terminology  used  in  these keys,  try  "[Plant Identification Terminology: An Illustrated Glossary](http://lib.du.ac.ir/documents/10157/60743/Plant+Identification+Terminology+Glossary.pdf)" (Harris & Harris, 2001)

Comment: I am from another country who just move in here and  I already try all those words that you show me but still did not get how those plants look like some kind of group. That's why I try to ask more specific word.

Comment: @SiriwanLaoketkit This is not a guide to keywords for google, it was a guide to identification  key websites and books which help you identify plants, usually by a step by step questionnaire. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identification_key